# CSS - How to make <div> side by side not wrap when user make browser size changing?

Tags: html, css

CSS -  How to make  side by side not wrap when user make browser size changing?
http://jsfiddle.net/QWSHw/

```
<div class="a">
<div class="gridrow">
    <div class="griditem">a
    </div>
    <div class="griditem">b
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 .a{
background: black;
position: absolute;
top:10px;
width:100%;
}
.gridrow{
background: gray;
width:100%;
}
.griditem{
background: blue;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:300px;
}​
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Even if you already get answers, please, be mor gentle and talkative. Explain us clearly (next time) what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `float: left`, the only thing you can do is set a `min-width` rule for the `.gridrow`

```
.gridrow{
    background: gray;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

Of course this impose a min screen size of `600px`, if the user resize the browser window to less than `600px` then the horizontal scroll bar will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `min-width:` on your containing Div. This will stop it from decreasing in size to the extent that your content wraps around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but i can guess you are talking about responsive, or adaptive design.

you need to set your width value in '%' instead of 'px', that will cause the browser to calculate the width on each viewport change and adjust accordingly

i recommend you use a css framework:

[twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

[foundation3](http://foundation.zurb.com/)